# FreeRTOS blocking on multiple events/objects

Tags: queue, semaphore, rtos, freertos

In the UDP/IP Stack solution example, [here](http://www.freertos.org/Pend-on-multiple-rtos-objects.html), there is a proposed solution for blocking on a single event queue.

What would be the go to solution for protecting the data that the pointer points to until it has been handled by the task waiting for the queue.

Say for example that the queue is filled from a ISR. The ISR should not write to `*pvData` if it has not been processed by the appropriate task. But since there can be several event sources the queue should probably be longer than one item. Should the struct be made:

```
typedef struct IP_TASK_COMMANDS
{
    eIPEvent_t eEventType;
    SemaphoreHandle_t data_read;
    void *pvData;
} xIPStackEvent_t;
```

With the semaphore taken in the ISR and given in the task that processes the data when it's done with it.

Comment: The title of this question suggests something quire different than the actual question.  The title suggests blocking on multiple queues.  You might do well to remove that ambiguity.

Comment: @Clifford I basically just stole the title of the FreeRTOS page on the subject but I get your point. Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the UDP example - normally you would have a pool of buffers (or dynamically allocate a buffer) from which a buffer would be obtained and given to the DMA.  When the DMA fills the buffer with received data a pointer to the buffer goes into the UDP stack - at which point only the UDP stack knows where the buffer is and is responsible for it.  At some point the data in the buffer may get passed from the UDP stack to the application where it can be consumed.  The application then returns the buffer to the pool (or frees the allocated buffer) so it is available to the DMA again.  The reverse is also true - the application may allocate a buffer that is filled with data to be sent, via the UDP stack, to the Tx function where it is actually placed onto the wire - in which case it is the Tx end interrupt that returns the buffer to the pool.

So, in short, there is only one thing that has a reference to the buffer at a time, so there is no problem.

[note above where it says the application allocates or frees a buffer, that would be inside the UDP/IP stack API called by the application rather than by the application directly - this is in fact partly at least how our own [TCP/IP](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/index.html) stack is implemented.]

Answer (score 1):

You don't want your ISR to block and wait for the data buffer to become available.  If it's appropriate for your ISR to just skip the update and move on when the buffer is not available then perhaps a semaphore makes sense.  But the ISR should not block on the semaphore.

Here's an alternative to consider.  Make a memory pool containing multiple appropriately sized data buffers.  The ISR allocates the next available buffer from the pool, writes the data to it and puts the pointer to it on the queue.  The task reads the pointer from the queue, uses the data, and then frees the buffer back to the pool.  If the ISR runs again before the task uses the data, the ISR will be allocating a fresh buffer so it won't be overwriting the previous data.

Here's another consideration.  The FreeRTOS Queue passes items by copy.  If the data buffer is relatively small then perhaps it makes sense to just pass the data structure rather than a pointer to the data structure.  If you pass the data structure then the queue service will make a copy to provide to the task and the ISR is free to update it's original buffer.

Now that I think about it, using the Queue service copy feature may be simpler than creating your own separate memory pool.  When you create the Queue and specify the queue length and item size, I believe the queue service creates a memory pool to be used by the queue.

Comment: I have considered that approach but since some events are not associated with any data and other have data I am looking for an approach where I don't have to copy data if there is none.